# Disable rotation during textField editing?

Tags: iphone, xcode4, textfield

is it possible to disable orientation rotating during textField editing? For example, it's possible to rotate app between portrait and landscape, but if you tap a text field in portrait, you can't rotate to landscape until your done editing? or vice versa if your in landscape?

I'm thinking if there is a way to do this, I'd be implementing it in textFieldDidBeginEditing and textFieldDidEndEditing

any help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: Is that a good user interface? Looks rather unuintuitive to me, and would likely add issues to your support log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your textField delegate to be the view controller.  When the textfield lets you know it's going to edit (I believe it's something like `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField`) set an iVar to your current orientation (_orientation = self.interfaceOrientation) and set a BOOL iVar(I'd call it _editing) to YES.  In the method `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation` return NO if it's not the orientation of the iVar and _editing is YES.

Comment: Or, to make it more simple without the delegate: `return ![textfield isFirstResponder];` (inside of the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method)

Comment: hmm, I'm relatively new to Xcode, so I'm not sure exactly how to implement that, so I'll do a little more research now that you guys have pointed me in the right direction, thank you

Comment: okay, I got it to do exactly what i needed, i just needed to take a step back to realize how i needed to code it